# load another site content - change style site for mobile version

Tags: javascript

Sorry.My English is poor.

I want, load another site - change(delete) style site - load my style version mobile to Site loaded.

I (file_get_contents ... str_replace) I used was not

I curl I used was not

I iframe I used was not

Orginal(before) site code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>sample</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<p id="sample">sample<p>
</body>
</html>
```

After Load site :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>sample</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my-style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p id="sample">sample<p>
</body>
</html>
```

### TNX.

Sorry.My English is poor.

Comment: where's the php code ?

Comment: Please post your php code.

Comment: **WHERE IS YOUR PHP CODE !**  If you don't understand  go to google translate. https://translate.google.com/

Comment: What's not working with your code ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand what you need.